# How to make a just on side border?

Tags: tcolorbox

here is a MWE:

```
\tcbox[enhanced,frame hidden,borderline={0.5pt}{0pt}{red,dashed}]{ab}
```

This is the result:
[image]

I want that the only the left border will appear. It is possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `borderline west` option for this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}         % for sample text
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{
   enhanced, frame hidden, borderline west = {0.5pt}{0pt}{red,dashed}, #1
}

% Variant using a `minipage`-style boxing technique (this allows
% multiple lines, \tcblower, etc.)
\newtcolorbox{myleftlinebox}[1][]{
   enhanced, frame hidden, borderline west = {0.5pt}{0pt}{red,dashed}, #1
}

\begin{document}

This is \mybox{the box} and what comes next.

\bigskip
This is \mybox[on line]{the same box but \texttt{on line}} and what comes
next.

\bigskip \noindent
Variant based on \verb|\newtcolorbox|:
\begin{myleftlinebox}
  \kant[1]
\end{myleftlinebox}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Note that the previous example can be factored out using a style declared with `\tcbset`, for instance:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}         % for sample text
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\tcbset{my left line/.style={
          enhanced, frame hidden, borderline west = {0.5pt}{0pt}{red,dashed}
}}

\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{my left line, #1}
\newtcolorbox{myleftlinebox}[1][]{my left line, #1}

\begin{document}

This is \mybox{the box} and what comes next.

\bigskip
This is \mybox[on line]{the same box but \texttt{on line}} and what comes
next.

\bigskip \noindent
Variant based on \verb|\newtcolorbox|:
\begin{myleftlinebox}
  \kant[1]
  \tcblower
  \kant[2]
\end{myleftlinebox}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]